# Switch between r.js optimized file and requirejs script loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I removed requirejs.config() from main.js in order to use r.js optimizer.
Exported file works like a charm but now main.js will not parse the config.

I'm looking for a dummy way (e.g. uncommenting script tag) to switch between r.js optimized file and requirejs script loading. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Why did you remove your config from `main.js`? `r.js` is quite capable of reading a `.js` file to extract the configuration from it.

Comment: @Louis are you sure about that?

"Error: Error: Build file <path>/js/main.js is malformed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; at Function.build.createConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:26708:23)

Comment: There must be something special about your `main.js`.

Comment: the optimizer's SyntaxErrors can be caused by running the build script the wrong way, more likely on Windows. I got the exact same error (`Unexpected token ;`) by running the script like this: `r.js build.js`; but `node build.js` builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main.js you can just require the config.js file before requiring any other dependencies. Basically you just wrap everything inside main.js with a require call:

```
require(['config'], function(){
  // The start of your old main.js file.
  require(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], function(foo, bar, baz){
    // Do stuff with foo, bar, and baz
  });
});
```

Comment: i tried this approach, the config is loaded but it is not parsed by requirejs for dependency resolution. Any thoughts?

Comment: In the r.js config make sure you specify `findNestedDependencies: true`.

Comment: See here for all the available options you can use in your config file: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js